# Application freezes when clicks button

Tags: c#

When I click the button the application window does not show anything and freezes. below is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int size = 5;
    int[] values= new int[size];

    int index = 0;
    string path ="nav.txt";

    StreamReader input;

    input = File.OpenText(path);

    while (index < values.Length && !input.EndOfStream) ;
    { 
        values[index] = int.Parse(input.ReadLine());
        index++;
    }

    foreach (int value in values)
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: most likely because the UI thread was blocked

Comment: Remove `;` after while loop. :)

Comment: Step 1. Right click on project in Visual Studio. Step 2. Select the "Build" tab. Step 3. Find the "Treat warnings as errors" section and select "All". Step 4. Profit! For the added win, install VS Refactoring Essentials and fix all errors, warnings and messages. This will ensure you have done everything in your power to reduce the number of errors, regardless of your programming experience and skills.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the compiler warnings, you'll see warning [CS0642](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x19t380(v=vs.90).aspx) which states:

> "Possible mistaken empty statement"

What this effectively means is that this piece of code:

```
while (index < values.Length && !input.EndOfStream) ;
{ 
    values[index] = int.Parse(input.ReadLine());
    index++;
}
```

Will not execute the while loops *body*, but will only loop through the condition inside the while loop, ignoring the body completely, possibly causing an endless loop. This happens because you have a trailing semicolon after the closing parenthesis.

Another possibility of doing IO work (in-case you need to process more than 5 lines), is going the asynchronous way.

Asynchronous IO which will release the thread while the IO operation is ongoing, allowing the message loop to process more events:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int size = 5;
    int[] values = new int[size];

    int index = 0;
    string path = "nav.txt";

    StreamReader input = File.OpenText(path);
    while (index < values.Length && !input.EndOfStream)
    {
        values[index] = int.Parse(await input.ReadLineAsync());
        index++;
    }

    foreach (int value in values)
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: I think the code only reads 5 lines at most (without the empty statement)

Comment: @HughJones You're right. I wanted to give the async IO part mainly for the benefit of doing things the async way. Updated the answer to convey that.

Comment: Yes I can see that.  I just thought it was worth stating in case it caused confusion later

Answer (score 0):

There doesnt need to be a ; after the While loop, this might fix it

Comment: Care to explain why this helps?

Comment: because with the semicolon there, nothing will increment index and the while will keep running forever

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the already mentioned ; on the while, if the file is big, you may experience GUI freeze because of the UI Thread being busy doing your stuff

if using Application.DoEvents() in the loop isn't enough, i suggest to you to use Tasks
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

P.S.
about the ; after the while, this is a big mistake because it is like writing 
while(condition){
}

so an empty body for the while loop, and since your while condition is "loop until i reach the end of the file", that condition will never been met, because your read operation isn't in the while body